# solr don't send the id field with the result

Tags: solr

i am pretty new to solr. and i don't know what is the best practice for the id column.

currently i wish to exclude the internal "id" parameter from `solr` search results (i am using my custom user_id field ).

i know i can use the `fl=field1,field2`. but this means specifying all my fields here. and i don't have a deep knowledge in solr and i fear this will hurt performance. ?

another question is it recommended to add another field `user_id` or overwrite the default `id` field ?

thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the value you have in your `user_id` field is unique, index that into your `id` column or define the `user_id` field as your unique key instead and don't use the `id` field.

The important thing is that there's a unique field in your document so that Solr knows when a document should be updated compared to when a new document should be added instead.

If the `id` field is not relevant / secret, I'm not sure why you'd be worried about including it.

Comment: thank you very much, another question will be. is there better performance between string and pint as id ?

Comment: Use strings. pints aren't well suited to be unique keys because of how they're processed in the background.